# Tauri blank screen running npm dev with Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, rust, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, tauri

An error is shown when trying to run tauti application in dev mode.

I'm using nuxt 3 as part of frontend application.

When trying to run build command the same error is shown and the package is not created

[image]

nuxt-config

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: false,

  modules: [
    '@vueuse/nuxt',
    '@unocss/nuxt',
    '@pinia/nuxt',
    '@nuxtjs/color-mode',
  ],
  experimental: {
    reactivityTransform: true,
    viteNode: false,
  },
  unocss: {
    preflight: true,
  },
  colorMode: {
    classSuffix: '',
  },
})
```

info

```
Environment
  › OS: Windows 10.0.22000 X64
  › Webview2: 103.0.1264.71
  › MSVC: 
  › Node.js: 16.15.0
  › npm: 8.11.0
  › pnpm: Not installed!
  › yarn: Not installed!
  › rustup: 1.25.1
  › rustc: 1.62.1
  › cargo: 1.62.1
  › Rust toolchain: stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc 

Packages
  › @tauri-apps/cli [NPM]: 1.0.5
  › @tauri-apps/api [NPM]: 1.0.2
  › tauri [RUST]: 1.0.0-rc.9,
  › tauri-build [RUST]: 1.0.0-rc.8,
  › tao [RUST]: 0.8.4,
  › wry [RUST]: 0.16.0,

App
  › build-type: bundle
  › CSP: unset
  › distDir: ../.output/public
  › devPath: http://localhost:3000/
  › framework: Vue.js (Nuxt)
  › bundler: Webpack

App directory structure
  ├─ .idea
  ├─ .nuxt
  ├─ .vscode
  ├─ components
  ├─ composables
  ├─ layouts
  ├─ node_modules
  ├─ pages
  ├─ public
  ├─ server
  └─ src-tauri
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

By Amr on Discord.

can you try upgrading your rust dependencies? they are outdated
tauri and tauri-build in src-tauri/Cargo.toml
then run cargo update in src-tauri
you can find the latest version numbers here https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri#current-releases btw